# My code for merge sort is not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, mergesort

So I have this merge sort code which works in java but the same is not working in JS. It's only sorting 1 element in 1 call. If I run the main merge function n( i.e arr.length-1) times then it sorts all the values. I want to find the mistake in this code or do I need to do some change to implement it in javascript. It looks like some recursive steps are not fully working in this code.

```js
let arr = [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
let sorted_arr = arr;
merge(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);

console.log('sorted_arr==', sorted_arr) //Array [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 8]

function merge(arr, lb, hb) {
  if (lb >= hb)
    return
  mid = parseInt((hb + lb) / 2);
  merge(arr, lb, mid);
  merge(arr, mid + 1, hb);
  sort(arr, lb, mid, hb)
}

function sort(arr, lb, mid, hb) {
  let b = [];
  let i = lb,
    j = mid + 1;
  k = 0
  while (i <= mid && j <= hb) {
    if (arr[i] <= arr[j]) {
      b[k] = arr[i];
      i++;
      k++
    } else {
      b[k] = arr[j];
      j++;
      k++
    }
  }

  while (i <= mid) {
    b[k] = arr[i];
    i++;
    k++;
  }

  while (j <= hb) {
    b[k] = arr[j];
    j++;
    k++;
  }

  for (q = 0, w = lb; q < b.length; q++, w++)
    sorted_arr[w] = b[q]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues:

- In the last loop, you should copy back the modified array over the original array, otherwise the merge phase of the caller will use the unsorted values and fail to merge properly.
- Also be aware that `sorted_arr = arr` makes `sorted_arr` and `arr` point to the same array.
- avoid missing `;`
- in the definition `let i = lb, j = mid + 1; k = 0`, `k` is not defined as a local variable, it is a global variable.
- Similarly, `q` and `w` are not defined as local variables.
- `parseInt((hb + lb) / 2)` is very inefficient: it converts the result to a string and parses the string back as an integer.  Instead you should write `let mid = (hb + lb) >> 1;`

Here is a modified version:

```
let arr = [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
merge(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);

console.log('sorted_arr==', sorted_arr) //Array [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 8]

function merge(arr, lb, hb) {
  if (lb >= hb)
    return
  mid = (hb + lb) >> 1;
  merge(arr, lb, mid);
  merge(arr, mid + 1, hb);
  sort(arr, lb, mid, hb)
}

function sort(arr, lb, mid, hb) {
  let b = [];
  let i = lb, j = mid + 1, k = 0;
  while (i <= mid && j <= hb) {
    if (arr[i] <= arr[j]) {
      b[k] = arr[i];
      i++;
      k++
    } else {
      b[k] = arr[j];
      j++;
      k++
    }
  }

  while (i <= mid) {
    b[k] = arr[i];
    i++;
    k++;
  }

  while (j <= hb) {
    b[k] = arr[j];
    j++;
    k++;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
    arr[lb + i] = b[j];
}
```